# Adjust Views Responsive in Flutter with Vertically and Horizontally Direction

Tags: android, flutter, dart, scaffold

I made this layout but I don't know how to make responsive views for all device.

I Put my both output Images as below.

back logout arrow(RightTop) and Image(Middle).

I give fix margin to the logout arrow. and adjust view for Image in Center alignment.

This is Vertical
[image]

This is Horizontal

[image]

and this is my code of design.

```
  import 'dart:io';
  
  import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
  import 'package:toast/toast.dart';
  
  import 'CurvedPainter.dart';
  
  void main() => runApp(Profile());
  
  class Profile extends StatelessWidget {
    const Profile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
    static const String _title = 'Profile';
  
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return const MaterialApp(
        title: _title,
        home: MyStatefulProfile(),
      );
    }
  }
  
  class MyStatefulProfile extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyStatefulProfile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyProfileState();
  }
  
  class MyProfileState extends State<StatefulWidget> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      final _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

return Scaffold(
  body: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    child: Stack(
      // use for adjust views stack wise in app.
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color(0xFFFFD700),
          ),
          child: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new CustomPaint(
                size: Size(_width, _height),
                painter: CurvedPainter(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        new InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print('Logout Clicked');
            logout();
          },
          child: new Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(290, 0, 0, 430),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.logout,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 150),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage('assets/images/ic_logo_main.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
              ),
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle),
        ),
      ],
    ),

 
  ),
);
}
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `Stack` use aligned widgets like `Positined`,`Align` to place the children.

For `log out button` it can be

```dart
   Positioned(
              right: 20,
              top: 20,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
  .....
```

or

```dart
       Align(
              alignment: Alignment(.9, -.9),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  print('Logout Clicked');
                  // logout();
                },
```

And for `ic_logo_main`

```dart
         Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Container(
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
                // margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 150), // not needed
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: new AssetImage('assets/images/ic_logo_main.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                    )
```

Wrap with positioned widget for every child inside `Stack` widget.

More about

- [Stack-class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) ,
- [Positioned widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgtPleVwxBQ)
- [Alignment-class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Alignment-class.html)

Comment: Thank you So much @YeasinSheikh it is work. and if you have any soft material about designing of flutter then plz share that link with me.

Comment: I follow https://flutter.dev/,  https://pub.dev/ and you can find `flutter` official channel on youtube, my fav is widgets of the week

Comment: Ok Thank you Again Yeasin.☺

Answer (score 3):

Use [responsive_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_builder) or [responsive_framework](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework) libraries.

whit responsive_builder you can do like this and return another widget for every screen tyoe :

```
ResponsiveBuilder(
    builder: (context, sizingInformation) {
      // Check the sizing information here and return your UI
          if (sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.desktop) {
          return Container(color:Colors.blue);
        }

        if (sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.tablet) {
          return Container(color:Colors.red);
        }

        if (sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.watch) {
          return Container(color:Colors.yellow);
        }

        return Container(color:Colors.purple);
      },
    },
  );
}
```